# Why can I not access the static member of this matplotlib class

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand why I cannot access static member `toolitems` from class `NavigationToolbar2QT`. In order to investigate this problem I've done the following:

```
imp.find_module('matplotlib')
>>> (None, '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib', ('', '', 5))
```

Ok. so now I'm sure where the module matplotlib is located, if I open `usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib/backends/backends_qt.py` then I find the class `NavigationToolbar2QT` with static member `toolitems`

```
class NavigationToolbar2QT( NavigationToolbar2, qt.QWidget ):
    # list of toolitems to add to the toolbar, format is:
    # text, tooltip_text, image_file, callback(str)
    toolitems = (
        ('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home.ppm', 'home'),
        ('Back', 'Back to  previous view','back.ppm', 'back'),
        ('Forward', 'Forward to next view','forward.ppm', 'forward'),
        (None, None, None, None),
        ('Pan', 'Pan axes with left mouse, zoom with right', 'move.ppm', 'pan'),
        ('Zoom', 'Zoom to rectangle','zoom_to_rect.ppm', 'zoom'),
        (None, None, None, None),
        ('Subplots', 'Configure subplots','subplots.png', 'configure_subplots'),
        ('Save', 'Save the figure','filesave.ppm', 'save_figure'),
        )
```

Now if I do the following:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4 import NavigationToolbar2QT
print NavigationToolbar2QT.toolitems
>>> AttributeError: type object 'NavigationToolbar2QT' has no attribute 'toolitems'
```

And this is where I'm a bit stuck, why can I not access this static member? I must be missing something trivial here.

Comment: You're looking at the code for usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib/backends/backends_qt.py but you're importing the code from `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4` - not the same modules. Also, if I browse the source on github, `backend_qt4` imports `NavigationToolbar2QT` from `backend_qt5` (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py#L35), which doesnt have a `toolbar` class attribute (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py#L566)

Comment: Thx! I was bouncing my head to the keyboard so hard, that i've missed that. This was indeed the problem, affortunately I cannot accept this as the correct answer because you've placed this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! As commented by bruno, I was looking at the wrong path. I was looking at the code for `usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib/backends/backends_qt.py` but I'm importing the code `from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4`, these are not the same modules.

Comment: `from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4` does have `.toolitems` depending on what version of matplotlib you have installed